# Equation with fractional parts

Tags: contest-math

How many solutions has the equation:

$\{20 \cdot \{ 13 \cdot\{20 \cdot\{ 13\cdot x\}\} \}\}=x^{2013}$ -?

Here $\{z\}=z-[z]$, where $[z]=m \in \mathbb{Z}, \ m \le z < m+1$.

Comment: Not, I trust, an ongoing contest?

Comment: No, of course .

Comment: Good. What contest, then?

Answer (score 1):

$20\cdot 13\cdot 20\cdot 13$ nonnegative solutions. $x^{2013}$ is in $[0,1]$ for $x\in[0,1]$. For nonnegative $x$, the LHS is a collection of affine pieces with slopes $20\cdot 13\cdot 20\cdot 13$. Each piece covers $y$-axis values between $0$ and $1$. In $[0,1]$ there are $20\cdot 13\cdot 20\cdot 13$ such pieces and $x^{2013}$ intersects with each of them once.

Comment: That was my answer too. It's wrong :(

Comment: Interesting, something about the slope of $x^{2013}$ perhaps, e.g. intersects some affine piece more than once. If this is the case, then probably near $1$. This thing can be numerically calculated in e.g. Mathematica, but I don't want to spend the time now.